# Java RegularExpression for " double quotes and ' ' spaces

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find and replace in the file using java but unable to get the solution.

File contents are

**"ProductCode" = "8:{3E3CDCB6-286C-4B7F-BCA6-D347A4AE37F5}"**

**"ProductCode" = "8:.NETFramework,Version=v4.5"**

I have to update the guid of first one which is **3E3CDCB6-286C-4B7F-BCA6-D347A4AE37F5**

```
String line = "\"ProductCode\" = \"8:{3E3CDCB6-286C-4B7F-BCA6-D347A4AE37F5}\"";
String pattern = "[\"]([P][r][o][d][u][c][t][C][o][d][e]).+([\"])(\\s)[\"][8][:][{]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

I am getting false.

please provide the solution if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your actual expected output for the `ProductCode` after you have applied some regex to it?

Comment: `Matcher.matches()` should match the whole string. Use `find()` if you wan't to check for partial match.

Comment: Constructs with a single letter in square brackets are redundant. You can simply use `ProductCode` instead `[P][r][o][d][u][c][t][C][o][d][e]`. Try to simplify your regex.

Comment: The equal-sign seems to be missing in the regex. You don't need [] around a single letter. I think you test the whole string for matching, but the regex only covers a part of it.

Comment: @mm759 There is a `.+` there.

Comment: Right. + is greedy. So, .+ "eats" the whole remaining part of the string and there is nothing more left for the remaining part of the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"ProductCode" = "8:{3E3CDCB6-286C-4B7F-BCA6-D347A4AE37F5}"** This is of the form:

```
quote + ProductCode + quote + whitespace + equals + whitespace + 
quote + number + colon + any + quote
```

A simple Regex for this is `\"ProductCode\"\s*=\s*\"\d:(.+)\"`

When we escape this to a Java string we get `\\\"ProductCode\\\"\\s*=\\s*\\\"\\d:(.+)\\\"`

Comment: Thanks flkes, 

"\\\"ProductCode\\\"\\s*=\\s*\\\"\\d:\\{(.+)\\\""   i added one \\{ 
to distinguish  from first product code to another one.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
String pattern = "^\\\"(ProductCode)\\\"\\s\\=\\s\\\"\\w\\:\\{(\\w+\\-*\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+)\\}\\\"$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex for this problem is like taking a sledgehammer to break a nut. Rather simple:

```
final String line = "\"ProductCode\" = \"8:{3E3CDCB6-286C-4B7F-BCA6-D347A4AE37F5}\"";

final String prefix = "\"ProductCode\" = \"8:{";
final int prefixIndex = line.indexOf(prefix);

final String suffix = "}\"";
final int suffixIndex = line.indexOf(suffix);

final String guid = line.substring(prefixIndex + prefix.length(), suffixIndex);
```

Comment: I think this is a valid use-case for a regex.

Comment: That's not the question - if a regex works, it is a valid use-case. But before someone is too occupied with whether something could or could not, one should ask if one should regarding the complexity of a problem and its solution.

Comment: I agree with you, however, in this particular scenario I would argue that using Regex is a simpler (and safer) solution. What if there isn't always white-space between the equals? What if some entries begin with `7:{` instead of `8:{`? These problems are exactly what a Regex is great at solving; trying to adapt this code for those scenarios would leave this solution far more complex than need be.

Comment: But what if OP specified all valid use-cases already and has no need for regex at all? Ignoring the existence of X/Y problems, I assume that OP knows what he needs and is able to ask questions completely covering all his problems.